# Getting Attributes Values From XML FIle- Reflection

Tags: java, xml, swing

I want to get the attributes value from a xml file and place the value in a Jtable.

I used the `Class<?>` method to get the class of each unit in my Sortedset :
`Class<?> clazz = machine.getClass();`

(machine is an object running on an iterator `for(*something* machine : machines)`)

Then, I used `clazz.getDeclaredFields()` to set the attributes in the left side of the table.

```
for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields())
{
    table.setValueAt(field.getName(),i,0);
    if (breakpoint==i) //if the line number from the table is matching the correct attribute,
    break; //then break
    breakPoint++;
}
```

I'm looking for the function that takes the value of the attribute, which then I could place the value on the right side of the table.

Comment: So you have a class for your XML data... Why Do you need to read the fields from the class instead of accessing them directly via the getters?  Anyway, the answer is probably the Field.get method, perhaps combined with setAccessible(true); But why?

Comment: That's what I've been asked to do.
I tried to use the `Field.get()` Method but I don't know which object I need to use as a parameter

Comment: The actual object that stores the value in this field, as the field itself only has a reference to the class, not the instance. No clue what that is in your case. Whatever you call getClass on, I suppose.